# ZF2: assigning variables to the ViewModel through 'dispatch' Event

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have ZF2 application in some cases I want to get parameter 'number' from the routing and make it available to all views. I tried to use events but problem with my solution is that $number is then available only in the layout and not in the views. 
Here is my code

```
$sharedEvents = $moduleManager->getEventManager()->getSharedManager();
$sharedEvents->attach( __NAMESPACE__, 'dispatch', function ( $e ) {
    $route = $e->getRouteMatch();
    $number = $route->getParam( 'number' );
    $view = $e->getViewModel();
    $view->setVariable( 'searchQuery', $number );
}, 90 );
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved it is accessible in view through

```
$this->layout()->getVariable('searchQuery');
```

More about this topic is available [here](http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-2/access-view-variables-in-another-view-model/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you:

```
$childView = $e->getViewModel()->getChildren();

$childView[0]->searchQuery = $number;
```